# Create a Datetime Object in R from a date column (format date) and an hour column (format integer)

Tags: datetime

I need a simple code to combine a date object with a numeric hour object to a datetime. Preferably using lubridate.

[Excerpt from Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNZJZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wstemp2001_2002$Datetime <- as.POSIXct(paste(wstemp2001_2002$Date,
    as.character(wstemp2001_2002$Hour2)), format= "%Y-%m-%d %H", tz="UTC")
```

Found the answer myself. This is a base R version. I convert the hour object into a character and use the "paste" function to combine the two.

Also please when working with datetime, always use UTC!